# ¿Por qué INSERT INTO en SSMS no me reconoce una tabla?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

Estoy aprendiendo SQL con SSMS. Y al momento de insertar datos en los campos con INSERT INTO no me muestra la información que coloqué en la tabla. ¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: 1) En el insert desbes especificar las columnas, ej `insert into tabla (col1, col2) values (1, 2)`. 2) Que no te reconozca la tabla  es o por que no existe, la has escrito mal, o la acabas de crear

Comment: No es que no te reconoce la tabla. Leé el mensaje de error :)

Comment: No te reconoce la tabla, porque aún no has ejecutado el `Use PracticaDB`. Entonces estás en la base de datos "probablemente" `master` o la que disponga tú login. Al no estar usando esa base de datos, no tiene la tabla. A veces cuando la acabas de crear tampoco la reconoce el SMS. Para eso usas el menú Editar y la opción Intellisense->Actualizar la cache local. Pero el error que te indica la ventana es que el número de columnas no encajan con la definición de la tabla. Usa mejor `insert into ProductDealer (col1, col2.....) Values (.....)`. Eso te ayudará a ver el error.